# Can't edit any files inside a .jws project in JDeveloper

Tags: java, project, java-web-start, jdeveloper

I can't edit any files inside this .jws project I'm working on. I click on any file (.xml, .java, or .jsp) and start typing and nothing happens.

Is this project in read-only mode or something? I see the following messages... not sure if it means anything.

Jun 14, 2017 5:53:01 PM oracle.security.jps.util.JpsUtil disableAudit
INFO: JpsUtil: isAuditDisabled set to true

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it has nothing to do with JDeveloper. My files were all set to read only on the Disk. I found out because I opened up the files in NotePad and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify these files as these are under source code control at server side. You need to create a working ade view. So, checkout the file you want to modify and than check in once all changes done

```
ade begintrans  <your transaction name>
ade co  <file name which you want to modify>
ade ci  <after modification, check in to ade>
ade savetrans
```